# Any way to access all MS Word 2016 content controls?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I'm using the Word JS API v1.1 to create a Word 2016 add-in. The add-in needs to be able to manipulate any content controls in a document, but currently the API is limited to rich text content controls only. Is it possible to use Office.js or any other tool to access all content control subtypes (checkbox, drop down list, etc.)?

Edit:

I can manipulate content controls the way I need to using VBA macros. Is it possible to associate a Word VBA macro with my add-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix VSTO and Office.js, they are entirely different frameworks.

With v1.1, [only Rich Text controls](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/contentcontrol) are supported. Support for subtypes looks to be coming in [v1.3](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/contentcontrol.md).

Comment: That isn't possible either. Add-ins run on a remote web server and are cross platform. VBA and VSTO run locally on your desktop. They each operate within their own sandboxes.

Answer (score 1):

to clarify 1.3 is not including support for all type of content controls, that will come in a later requirement version.